# ErrorException : Array to string conversion in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, html

I want to convert an array to a string in Laravel. I have already searched and implement the `implode()` function to convert this but got this error

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion
```

**Here is my code in controller**

```
$sliderImageDataArray[] =array(
                "title"=> $value->title,
                "text"=> "<p><span id=\"hs_cos_wrapper_module_1498510869515998\" class=\"hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container\" data-hs-cos-general-type=\"widget_container\" data-hs-cos-type=\"widget_container\">".$value->text."<\/span><\/p>\n<p><a class=\"btn  btn-secondary\" href=\"http://localhost/sencare/book-appoinment/\" target=\"_self\">  Make An Appointment <\/a>\u00a0<a class=\"btn  btn-light\" href=\"http://localhost/sencare/our-doctors/\" target=\"_self\"> Our Doctors<\/a><\/p>\n",
                "is_video"=> false,
            );

$sliderImageDataArray = implode(" ",$sliderImageDataArray);

return $sliderImageDataArray;
```

Anybody help please

Comment: We can’t help you if you post no code.

Comment: @ishegg..... I have update my post. please check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the following code

```
{!! str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($sliderImageDataArray)) !!};
```

instead of

```
$sliderImageDataArray = implode(" ",$sliderImageDataArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the `[]` after `$sliderImageDataArray`. You're actually assigning the array with those values to the *first element* of the array that is `$sliderImageDataArray`. So, `implode()` actually tries to join by that array, not the one inside. And since the resulting pieces are an array, not a string, it gives you the `Array to string conversion` error. Remove the `[]`:

```
<?php
$sliderImageDataArray =array(
                "title"=> "test title",
                "text"=> "<p><span id=\"hs_cos_wrapper_module_1498510869515998\" class=\"hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget_container hs_cos_wrapper_type_widget_container\" data-hs-cos-general-type=\"widget_container\" data-hs-cos-type=\"widget_container\">value<\/span><\/p>\n<p><a class=\"btn  btn-secondary\" href=\"http://localhost/sencare/book-appoinment/\" target=\"_self\">  Make An Appointment <\/a>\u00a0<a class=\"btn  btn-light\" href=\"http://localhost/sencare/our-doctors/\" target=\"_self\"> Our Doctors<\/a><\/p>\n",
                "is_video"=> false,
            );

$sliderImageDataArray = implode(" ",$sliderImageDataArray);

echo $sliderImageDataArray;
```

And it works correctly.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/K9HMA)

Comment: I have a bunch of data getting from database and need to keep them in an array format and send them to the view. That's why I used `[]` in `sliderImageDataArray`.

Comment: I see, but `implode()` can't join `array`s. You'll need to loop `$sliderImageDataArray ` with `foreach()` and implode each element individually.

Comment: @ishegg.....please see this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970613/how-to-convert-a-full-array-into-a-string-in-laravel]

Comment: Ohh sorry my friend for not giving the answer here yet...yes ... Here is the answer....`{!! str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($sliderImageDataArray)) !!};`